# Where do I create the config.yml file when deploying openedx on Ubuntu？

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, openedx

There is a step in the openedx installation instructions:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEzuI.png)

However, no directory was created during the installation,So in which directory should I create the config.yml file?

Here is the installation instructions link:[text](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/1969455764/Koa+Native+Open+edX+platform+Ubuntu+20.04+64+bit+Installation)

I previously tried to omit the step of creating the config.yml file, but eventually deploying openedx failed.

Answer (score 0):

This instruction page is for Open edX "Koa" version installation. If you install the Koa version, create the config.yml file in your home folder.

In case if you are going to install Open edX latest version, please use Open edX Tutor version. Installation instructions [here](https://docs.tutor.overhang.io/).

Comment: Once I have created this config.yml file, what steps do I need to use this configuration file in the subsequent installation process? I can't find in the official installation instructions which step will use this configuration file?

Comment: What version are you going to install?

Comment: I've chosen the koa version for now, but if there are other versions that can be successfully installed, that's fine.

Comment: Please read the document I have mentioned above. Koa is quite old now. The latest version is Palm.